# How to Zip a folders and download

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the download of files. It is downloading and saving it to memory.

Now my problem is, if there is folder and sub folder, I need to ZIP the folder and download the zip file and save it in memory. I tried lot but I did'nt find a solution. Can any one can guide me to get the solution?

Here my download single file code...

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP "
                        + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                        + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            String fileName = tvtitle.getText().toString();
            String fileExtension = tvtype.getText().toString();

            File imageDirectory = new File(Path);
            imageDirectory.mkdirs();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            String _path = Path;
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            File outputFile = new File(_path, fileName + fileExtension);
            output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            // zos = new ZipOutputStream(output);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;

                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Actually you should write code for zipping on server. Android will simply download whatever is given.

Comment: there is ZipOutputStream method id there but i dnt knw how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

call this method by passing "inputFolderPath" and "outputFolderPath"

```
private static void zipFolder(String inputFolderPath, String outZipPath)  {
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outZipPath);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    File srcFile = new File(inputFolderPath);
    File[] files = srcFile.listFiles();
    Log.d("", "Zip directory: " + srcFile.getName());
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Log.d("", "Adding file: " + files[i].getName());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
    }
    zos.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.e("", ioe.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: are you succeed to store data in local storage? if yes, than just you have to use this method by passing two parameters like first one is your local path where your download data available (without zip) and second one is your destination path(your data folder available with zip).

Comment: local path means can i send absolute path..?

Comment: YES, upto folder in where your data files available.

Comment: Even though i am passing the path. in files[i] it is showing null